# Using shapes in word 2007

Tags: windows-7, window

We are doing our own newsletter template- we have two rectangle shapes with contents etc running down the right handside of the page when we add text the second shape jumps to page two which we don't want it to.  Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that the size of the rectangle is not setting inside the window. Try reducing the size that fits in to the page and check

Answer (score 0):

Change page orientation and see if that works.

Or decrease the size of the shape.

If all else fails, move to a bigger paper size. Bigger is better in competitions.